# Windows not loading in GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hibernate

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on my machine and before installing ubuntu, I had a windows 10 on my machine. Before installing ubuntu, windows was hibernated and now I can't find it in my GRUB menu nor I can mount it with nautilus.

My machine had a Free DOS installation on it and now I technically should have 3 operating systems, but windows is not showing up.

I have tried using the boot-repair tool, but nothing changed.

Comment: At the time of installation you should not have Windows hibernated. Have you disabled fast boot in BIOS? Please share your GRUB config and screen shots.

Comment: You may have to use your Windows repair console on Windows repair/recovery drive to temporaily restore a Windows boot loader if installed in BIOS boot mode. IF UEFI just use UEFI boot menu to boot Windows. Turn off fast start up. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Then restore grub2's boot loader either with Boot-Repair or manually.

Comment: Ashu, this is the config file: http://pastebin.com/xejEQ183